# Using bit wise operators

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators

Am working on a C++ app in Windows platform. There's a unsigned char pointer that get's bytes in decimal format.

```
unsigned char array[160];
```

This will have values like this,

```
array[0] = 0
array[1] = 0
array[2] = 176
array[3] = 52

array[4] = 0
array[5] = 0
array[6] = 223
array[7] = 78

array[8] = 0
array[9] = 0
array[10] = 123
array[11] = 39

array[12] = 0
array[13] = 0
array[14] = 172
array[15] = 51

.......
........
.........
and so forth...
```

I need to take each block of 4 bytes and then calculate its decimal value.

So for eg., for the 1st 4 bytes the combined hex value is B034. Now i need to convert this to decimal and divide by 1000.

As you see, for each 4 byte block the 1st 2 bytes are always 0. So i can ignore those and then take the last 2 bytes of that block. So from above example, it's 176 & 52.

There're many ways of doing this, but i want to do it via using bit wise operators.

Below is what i tried, but it's not working. Basically am ignoring the 1st 2 bytes of every 4 byte block.

```
int index = 0

for (int i = 0 ; i <= 160; i++) {
        index++;
        index++;
        float Val =  ((Array[index]<<8)+Array[index+1])/1000.0f;

        index++;
    }
```

Comment: you cant shift the value more than its bitsize

Comment: `for (i <= 160)` is too big. You have only 40 of them.

Comment: So you know that you have 4 values, but you only increment 3 times? why not `for(int index = 0; index < 160; index +=4)`?

Comment: Please be more specific than "it's not working".

Comment: your index changes are wrong, fixe them

Comment: Now is an excellent opportunity for you to learn how to use your debugger. Your debugger will allow you to run your program one line at a time, examine the values of all variables as they change, and observe your program's execution flow. If you already knew how to use your debugger you would've immediately seen the bug in how you update your index variable, and you would've been able to fix it quickly yourself instead of asking strangers on the Internet to fix your code for you. At least you can learn how to use your debugger now, and you won't have ask anyone else for debugging help.

Comment: There are no "hex values" or "decimal values". `(0xb0 << 8) | 0x34` is exactly the same as `(176 << 8) | 52`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're processing the array four-by-four, I recommend that you increment `i` by 4 in the for loop. You can also avoid confusion after dropping the unnecessary `index` variable - you have `i` in the loop and can use it directly, no?

Another thing: Prefer bitwise OR over arithmetic addition when you're trying to "concatenate" numbers, although their outcome is identical.

```
for (int i = 0 ; i <= 160; i += 4) {
    float val = ((array[i + 2] << 8) | array[i + 3]) / 1000.0f;
}
```

Comment: If using bitwise operators, better to use an `unsigned` type than `long`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `i <= 160` is one iteration too many.

Second, your incrementation is wrong; for `index`, you have

```
Iteration 1:
    1, 2, 3
    And you're combining 2 and 3 - this is correct.
Iteration 2:
    4, 5, 6
    And you're combining 5 and 6 - should be 6 and 7.
Iteration 3:
    7, 8, 9
    And you're combining 8 and 9 - should be 10 and 11.
```

You need to increment four times per iteration, not three.

But I think it's simpler to start looping at the first index you're interested in - 2 - and increment by 4 (the "stride") directly:

```
for (int i = 2; i < 160; i += 4) {
    float Val = ((Array[i]<<8)+Array[i+1])/1000.0f;
}
```